# Casperjs: How to catch syntax errors of an included java script code in a page?

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, casperjs

Is there a way to catch javascript errors in Casperjs?

I've written a script for Casperjs to crawl a website and look for javascript errors of each page. 
Actually, I would like to catch all the javascript errors thrown by the JavaScript engine. As an  example, for the following script:

`<script  src="http://example.com/a/image.jpeg"> </script>`

Since JavaScript engine cannot interpret a jpeg file as a js file, it throws a syntax error in my browser console.

In order to catch such errors in Casperjs, I've tried remote.message, page.error, and resource.error handlers, but none of them works. remote.message only catches console.log, page.error should be fired in case of existing any uncaught js error but is not fired for the above example.

Would you please give me some hints on any other handlers or options that I can use to catch such errors?

Comment: This seems like a case of PhantomJS where nothing can be done about it. Do any of the event handlers change when you try an actual image url? Have tried to add the `type` attribute to the script tag so that PhantomJS knows it is supposed to parse it as JavaScript?

Comment: These are the list of event handlers I used: